# VSCode doesn't recognise Dart SDK (running on WSL)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the Windows version of the flutter SDK installed at C/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter on my Windows 10 machine, but do all my development through WSL1 using ohmyzsh as the shell and VS Code as the IDE. I resolved errors running flutter commands through zsh that resulted because of windows-style syntax:

> (e.g. /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line 5: $'\r':
> command not found)

by creating a shell script 'flutter' in my home directory that forces the flutter command to run through windows:

```
    #!/bin/bash
cmd.exe /c flutter.bat $@
```

Now this is my output in zsh from flutter doctor -v:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19042.1288], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.5.3 at C:\Users\OEM\Documents\flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 18116933e7 (3 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
> • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
> • Dart version 2.14.4
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension can be installed from:
>  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
> • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
> • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.30

Everything is working fine. However, VS Code fails to initialize Flutter when opening a project because it cannot find the Dart SDK. Here is the relevant part of the the error log:

> [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]     Found at: [11:55:40 AM] [General]
> [Info]         /home/jack-r-buckley [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]
> /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]
> Candidate paths to be post-filtered: [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]
> /home [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]
> /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]
> Returning SDK path undefined for dart [11:55:40 AM] [General] [Info]
> Flutter is not initialized, running 'flutter doctor' to force...
> [11:55:42 AM] [General] [Info] (PROC 1145) Logging data for process...
> [11:55:43 AM] [General] [Info] (PROC 1145)
> /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line 5: $'\r': command
> not found /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line 13:
> $'\r': command not found
> /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line 14: set: - :
> invalid option set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name]
> [--] [arg ...] /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line
> 15: $'\r': command not found
> /mnt/c/Users/OEM/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter: line 17: unset:
> `CDPATH ': not a valid identi… [11:55:43 AM] [General] [Info] (PROC
> 1145) exited (2, null)

I am pretty new to development so please forgive me if my approach is way off here. Is there a way to make VS Code recognise my Dart SDK within this setup? Or am I better off to just use powershell and get WSL out of the way entirely? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not certain this can't be made to work, it certainly isn't the way I (author of the Dart extension) would expect this to be used. When running in WSL, the Dart extension is running in Linux-land and makes assumptions that the Flutter process is too that might not hold true (for example it may capture PIDs and expect to be able to send signals to them).

If you want to run in WSL, I would recommend having a Flutter SDK set up inside WSL (which will download the Linux build of the Dart SDK). However, you may find that some functionality won't work as well this way (for example the WSL instance might not see devices connected in Windows).

If you don't have a real need to use WSL, I would suggest skipping it - it's just extra complexity you probably don't need. If you do need it, I'm interested in the use case though (it's always useful to understand what users of the extension are doing to avoid confusing like this).